# How do I access resource defined in App.xaml from OnLaunched?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I'm using the MVVM pattern with MVVM Light.  I have a ViewModelLocator defined in App.xaml which holds all the ViewModels which are bound to from the Views using Blend.

I have an AppViewModel which basically contains all the important global info for my app, like user preferences.  AppViewModel is instantiated by ViewModelLocator, which is in turn, instantiated by app.xaml.

The trouble is, I need to access AppViewModel from inside OnLaunched, however, at this stage of the application lifecycle, it appears app.xaml has not yet instantiated its declared resources.  It appears to only do this after a Frame.Navigate().

I need to access AppViewModel because I have to inspect the properties on there in order to work out which Page to load.  Hence it's a chicken-and-egg situation.

If I separately instantiate AppViewModel inside OnLaunched, then I can access AppViewModel, but then ViewModelLocator gets instantiated twice which causes problems with my IoC.

Is there a way of manually instantiating items declared inside app.xaml?  Or is there a way to get app.xaml to load its resources before presenting a UI?

Or am I doing this wrong? Generally speaking, I regard the application to be the view model layer and the views essentially observe that... so hence I need the ViewModels available before I present any UI.

XAML:

```
<Application.Resources>
<vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" />
</Application.Resources>
```

Code:

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    var vml = App.Current.Resources["Locator"] as ViewModelLocator; // exception raised
```

Exception:

> WinRT information: Cannot find a resource with the given key.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about you instantiate the `ViewModelLocator` when you first need it and then add it to `Application.Resources` once `Application.Resources` is otherwise initialized or whenever you need? You don't need to add key value pairs to the `ResourceDictionaries` in XAML always.

Comment: Because the app needs to be Blendable which means it has to be declared in xaml.

Comment: At least I think that it needs to be declared in App.xaml in order to enable bindings in Blend!?

Comment: No, it can just as well be defined in App.xaml.cs or anywhere you want. You just want to add it to `Application.Resources` if that is the way you want to be accessing your `ViewModelLocator`.

Comment: So I can add blendable resources to the App in the OnLaunched?  i.e., Blend fires OnLaunched at design time?

Comment: You're right it might not be the case. You might need a `ViewModelLocatorLocator` in XAML... :)
Or await XAML resources load in your `OnLaunched()` method.